# Typekit dosent work on Localhost

Tags: typekit

I did add localhost on kit settings but it dosen't still work.
Works perfectly on domain but not on localhost.

I Tried everything. Install easyphp or wamp.
Results are still same.

Comment: is your localhost server actually running?

Comment: yes, already running.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added localhost to your typekit kit itself?

[image: typekit kit settings]